# Role based authorizations or different tables in a ruby appointment booking app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have seen regular debates about the way to manage the different class of users.

- Usually, it seems that developers prefer a role based approach (e.g. user, admin,...) with gems like Cancancan
- But I'm wondering if it's applicable for an appointment booking app (appointment for doctors, teachers,... or even bookings). Indeed in this case, the 2 types of users have access to totally different pages. In its documentation about associations, Ruby on Rails guide takes the example of a medical appointment booking app with 1 table for doctors and 1 table for patients.

For this kind of app, I'm a little bit lost regarding the most efficient solution!
Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand your question - you can tweak cancancan to do whatever you want in an appointment booking app: e.g. only doctors can make doctors appointments, or teachers can make teacher appointments, or admin teacheres can only approve classes etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like Cancanan to break out the different roles and abilities, then restrict access to certain parts of the system based on those rules.

Additionally you can display only the relevant navigation or pages when the user's accessing the system so they might not even be aware of what they're not seeing.